# can not get immediately result when modify php file

Tags: php, cache-control

I used lnmp package to install lnmp, Now, I can not get the immediately result when I modify the php file.what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: do u using any cache? such as opcache, eaccelerate, apc, xcache...?

Comment: thanks very much,opcache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More details need to be provided for this question.

If you are using a php  framework its recommended setting it to developer mode.To avoid cache or alternatively clean the cache folder and refresh your browser

You also read on cache purging on nginx server

https://www.nginx.com/products/content-caching-nginx-plus/

Comment: I am not use any php framework for the test. when I modify the code from "<?php echo time(); ?> " to "<?php echo "11111"; ?>". if I want to display  1111 must to wait a moment ,too.

Comment: thanks, I have solved it. all the problems was I modified the wrong file of php.ini.